# converting java string dot to float number with json annotation

Tags: java, json, jackson-databind

I try to convert string to float with java json annotation.

```
public class EtlColumnPojo{
    
    @JsonProperty("value")
    private float value;
}
```

But some value strings are not number, but "." only. So it throws the following exceptions.

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `float` from String ".": not a valid Float value

So I make the custom json deserializer codes.

```
public class CustomFloatDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Float> {

    @Override
    public Float deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String floatString = p.getText();
        if(floatString.equals(".")) {
            return Float.valueOf(0);
        }
        
        return Float.valueOf(floatString);
    }

}
```

And I add the custom deserializer like below,

```
public class EtlColumnPojo{
    
    @JsonDeserialize(using = CustomFloatDeserializer.class)
    @JsonProperty("value")
    private float value;
}
```

It works successfully without the above exceptions. But I wonder these custom json deserializer codes are efficient. The value is dot only but I am afraid I make too much codes to solve this issue. Is there another way to solve these exceptions with only simple json annotations?

Comment: can this help you https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFormat.Shape.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can add to your `EtlColumnPojo` class a setter you can label it with the same `@JsonProperty("value")` annotation you're using or as the alternative one [`JsonSetter`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonSetter.html) annotation:

```
@JsonProperty("value")
public void setValue(String floatString) {
    value = floatString.equals(".") ? 0 : Float.valueOf(floatString);
}
```